# EmailJS not filling all variable fields?

Tags: vue.js

First time I'm using EmailJS, I've created my own email template but for some reason EmailJS is not filling all the fields I've specified. The emails do come through. Is it something I'm missing?

Code:

```
sendEmail(e) {
  try {
    console.log(this.klantNaam, this.klantEmail, this.klantAdres, this.klantDatum, this.klantVraag); 
    //all fields are populated in the console
    
    emailjs.sendForm('service_name', 'template_id', e.target,
    'public_key', {
      from_name: this.klantNaam,
      reply_to: this.klantEmail,
      adres: this.klantAdres,
      datum: this.klantDatum, //this is the only one that is sent correctly
      message: this.klantVraag,
    })
  } catch(error) {
      console.log({error}) //there is no error in the console
  } 
}
```

[image: Email template setup]

EDIT: Added Email HTML below:

```
<p><strong>Afzender:</strong></p>
<p>{{reply_to}}</p>
<p><strong>Nieuw bericht:</strong></p>
<p>{{message}}</p>
<p><strong>Adres:</strong></p>
<p>{{adres}}</p>
<p><strong>Wanneer komt het uit?</strong></p>
<p>{{datum}}</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><em>Automatisch gegenereerd bericht</em></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Can you share your emailtemplate html, please!?

Comment: @MaikLowrey I just added my source code!